# Timestamp in DB and java.util.Date in Entity causes rounding issue when loaded with OpenJPA

Tags: java, date, db2, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I am loading a value from the database, which is a Timestamp datatype in IBM DB2, but needs to be mapped as java.util.Date for the JSF GUI. I thought just tell JPA it is a timestamp and it will manage it. I did it this way:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE")
private Date myTimeStampAsDate;
```

However if there is the Date 9999-12-31 23:59:59 in the database it will be round up in my Entity to the date 10000-01-01 00:00

If I map it as a real java.sql.Timestamp it loads even the milliseconds perfectly. What do I need to do to avoid this "rounding behavior" but keep java.util.Date for my entity and the GUI?

Comment: Could be some sort of wierd implicit behaviour.  What happens if your entity uses the `java.sql.Timestamp`, and the JSF page creates a new `Date` by calling `Timestamp.getTime()` (which spits out millis).  Alternatively, could you just format the timestamp?

Comment: i will try to let JSF create a new date, however this solution means I need manipulated setters, which is not a good option imho. this issue is not just a formatting problem. I debugged it and reassured the behavior in an indepedent JUnit test: It is being loaded with this rounding, so it is a different value! thanks for your proposal. I will let you know how it behaves for the new date from the GUI

Comment: Oh, wait, are your JSFs running on a different JVM than the entity?  There's such a thing as leap seconds, which may or may not be implemented on different/different versions of JVMs.

Comment: @X-Zero I created two simple JUnit test projects and the date annotated with timestamp works correctly with Hibernate 4.0.1!
I will further investigate and fill you in if there are any news on this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openjpa will provide a data dictionary option to not round the milliseconds for `java.util.Date` properties annotated with `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`
. Hopefully it will come with version 2.2.1/2.3.X and ongoing. Please follow this Jira Issue to see when it will be entirely solved:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2159

The property seems to look like this in your `persistence.xml` (The default will be `true`):

`<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="roundTimeToMillisec=false" />`

The default will be `true`